# Centering and rotating bitmap via matrix.setTranslation() doesn't work on orientation change

Tags: android, matrix

I'm making a speedometer and I'm centering the needle via a setTranslation(). All works almost well in LANDSCAPE mode but when changing the orientation of the emulator to PORTRAIT, the needle has an **offset towards the left + top(+x, +y)**.

The sizes of my bitmap objects are:

speedo_meter(H x W): 89 x 20

needle(H x W): 344 x 313

But when using getWidth() and getHeight and displaying them with Log.d the values are different(see the end of the question for the LogCat).

**Can anyone explain the cause of the difference in values and the offset in PORTRAIT mode?**

**Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:**

[image: example]

**Here's the onDraw() method containing the Matrix:**

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawBitmap(speedo_meter, (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - speedo_meter.getWidth() / 2,
                                    (canvas.getHeight() / 3) - speedo_meter.getHeight() / 2, null);


        // Main Meter Needle
        matrix_needle.setTranslate((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - needle.getWidth() / 2,
                                   (canvas.getHeight() / 3)- needle.getHeight());

        // Log.d("ANGLE OF DEVIATION : ","" + angle_of_deviation);
        Log.d("CANVAS HEIGHT : ","" + canvas.getHeight());
        Log.d("CANVAS WIDTH : ","" + canvas.getWidth());

        Log.d("METER HEIGHT : ","" + speedo_meter.getHeight());
        Log.d("METER WIDTH : ","" + speedo_meter.getWidth());

        Log.d("NEEDLE HEIGHT : ","" + needle.getHeight());
        Log.d("NEEDLE WIDTH : ","" + needle.getWidth());

        Log.d("MATRIX : ","" + matrix_needle.toString());

        matrix_needle.postRotate(angle_of_deviation, canvas.getWidth() / 2, 2 * needle.getHeight() - 10);

        canvas.drawBitmap(needle, matrix_needle, paint_needle);

        // Main Meter Wheel
        canvas.drawBitmap(center_wheel, (canvas.getWidth() / 2)- center_wheel.getWidth() / 2,
                                        (canvas.getHeight() / 3)- center_wheel.getHeight() / 2, null);
}
```

**I'm creating a custom view like this:**

```
public SpeedometerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView(context);    
}

public SpeedometerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView(context);
}

public SpeedometerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initializeView(context);
}


//Create view
private void initializeView(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    speedo_obj = this;


    this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    releaseImageResources();

    speedo_meter = getImage(R.drawable.meter);

    center_wheel = getImage(R.drawable.center_wheel);

    needle = getImage(R.drawable.arrow);

    paint_needle = new Paint();
    paint_needle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint_needle.setAntiAlias(true);    
}
```

**And this is my layout XML with the custom view:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.speedometer.view.SpeedometerView
        android:id="@+id/speedometer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip" >
    </com.mobisoft.view.SpeedometerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_needle_value_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/move_needle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The relevant entries obtained via Log.d:**

LANSCAPE MODE:

```
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/CANVAS HEIGHT :(2859): 487
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/CANVAS WIDTH :(2859): 1024
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/METER HEIGHT :(2859): 229
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/METER WIDTH :(2859): 209
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/NEEDLE HEIGHT :(2859): 59
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/NEEDLE WIDTH :(2859): 13
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/MATRIX :(2859): Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 506.0][0.0, 1.0, 103.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
```

PORTRAIT MODE:

```
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/CANVAS HEIGHT :(2859): 911
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/CANVAS WIDTH :(2859): 600
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/METER HEIGHT :(2859): 229
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/METER WIDTH :(2859): 209
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/NEEDLE HEIGHT :(2859): 59
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/NEEDLE WIDTH :(2859): 13
03-28 16:50:19.033: D/MATRIX :(2859): Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 294.0][0.0, 1.0, 244.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the notification bar height, you can find out the height at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Comment: I have removed the title bar just to make sure it's not that.

Comment: And why do I have different values for my bitmaps?.. I have posted the original size of the .png files and the LogCat result when querying the H and W.

Comment: I mean the notification bar. I had a surface view with camera preview and I can get the the difference but in your case I do not know how to get the notification bar height. I do not know I think the OS scale your bitmap to fit the new dimension

Comment: It can't be the notification bar because my offsets are -x, -y(as I specified in my question... in BOLD). If the notification bar would be the cause of the offset then I should have a +y.

Comment: What I did is 2 years ago, but I was surprise to see part of my sphere top half was hidden. And it turned out to be the notification bar. Why don't you subtract out the notification bar height as given in the link above and see if things work out.

Comment: You have to add the the notification bar height to the vertical center of the picture you want to draw. That is what I did in my code.